# Modules over simple algebras.

Tags: modules, algebras

Let $A$ be a finite simple $k-$algebra.

1) There exists exactly one simple $A-$module $M$ up to isomorphism.

2) Any finite $A-$module is a direct sum of copies of a simple module.

3) Two finite $A-$modules are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension over $k$.

How do I prove 2) and 3)?

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of semisimple algebras?

Comment: No, not completely. What do I need from sempisimple algebras to prove this? 

(I'm familiar with semisimple modules and rings).

Comment: You need (essentially) that all finite dimensional modules over a simple algebra are semisimple (which with some definitions would mean to show that simple algebras are semisimple).